# How Activiti Workflow Retry mechanism work

Tags: workflow, activiti

From Activiti user guide (https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#failRetry), we can configure number of retries and retry interval as below:

```xml
<serviceTask id="failingServiceTask" activiti:async="true" activiti:class="org.activiti.engine.test.jobexecutor.RetryFailingDelegate">
    <extensionElements>      
        <activiti:failedJobRetryTimeCycle>R5/PT7M</activiti:failedJobRetryTimeCycle>
    </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

However, a job may contain many tasks, so it will get the retry configurations from which tasks? The first task of the job or the failed task?

Moreover do I need to put the retry configuration into every tasks?

<sub>(Note: Question also posted here: https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-process-services/how-activiti-workflow-retry-mechanism-work/td-p/292354 )</sub>

Comment: retry or rollback mechanism? the whole job will run again in case of failure

Comment: Retry. But for example if a job has 3 service tasks, it will get the configuration from which task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete entry of the job gets affected once an error is encountered. You can (and should) keep only one service task (generally a "JavaDelegate") per job.

Activiti works on managing wait-states. If an error is encountered, then the transaction back until the last wait-state is rolled back.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but in case I have 2 service tasks within same job, which configuration the job will take?

Comment: Ideally it would go to the first task. But it depends on your config. Of async and exclusive flag